# How can I add further controller method to my rails application but not overwrite the current controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I am using Spina CMS and it needs the routes engine to populate the front end from the back end.

So I cannot interfere with this as I still need my website CMS driven however I would like to add a further action to my homepage/all pages in addition to what Spina is already doing.

Is this possible?

Spina routes.rb engine:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Spina::Engine => '/'
end
```

I want to add my own controller and action:

```
class Default::PagesController < ApplicationController
    def homepage
        @thisisavariable = "hello"
    end
end
```

but if I add it to the routes.rb it will overwrite Spina:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/', to: 'default/pages#homepage'

  mount Spina::Engine => '/'
end
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question. What do you mean by 'method'? A new action? a new web page?

Comment: Do you want to keep the logic from original action as well as add some more variables e.g. `@thisisavariable = "hello"` before rendering the view? If that's what you want, you can assign them and call `super` at the end of action.

Comment: Yes I still want Spina to do it's thing but on top of that I want to add that variable - well in the future I want to add a contact form but for now I just want to be able to connect a controller to homepage and not overwrite what Spina is doing.

Comment: @lastone did you have a solution? for setting a landing page `/` ?